# Error: Cannot find module 'semver' Require stack: - having troubles with npm on windows

Tags: windows, npm, module, semantic-versioning

```
C:\Users\blobr>npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\blobr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js
- C:\Users\blobr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\blobr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\unsupported.js:2:14)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\blobr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\unsupported.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\blobr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

I'm having trouble with installing npm. Node is installed and everything. But, npm isn't installing. I've rebooted my pc a few times and still nothing. I even repaired it and restarted it and it still doesn't work. I'm on windows. Most of these issues happen with linux users and there are just linux terminal commands.

Comment: Can be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1438196/npm-error-cannot-find-module-semver/1438491#1438491

Comment: I am on windows, not linux.